# How to save render layers for later use

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

This is probably a silly question, but I'm struggling with it. When I close Blender and open it up again I now have to re-render the scene to be able to use them again in the compositor.

I have read some things about OpenEXR Multi-Layers but you have to save them individually I believe. Isn't there a function to assign some sort of fake user to the render layers?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply set the output format to *OpenEXR MultiLayer* and save the render, it will store all render passes. Create another project for the compositing where you load the image(s) through an *Image* node. All render passes will be available as sockets, if you set the *Layer* in the *Image* node to (one of) the *View Layer(s)* you've rendered.

Example of multi-layer OpenEXR opened through an *Image* node and usage of the stored Cryptomatte:
[image: Example Cryptomatte]

There are three relevant options for the multi-layer OpenEXR file format in the context of compositing:

- Color (Channels)
- Color Depth
- Codec

The color channels should always be set to *RGBA* in order to store associated alpha.

The color depth can either be set to *Float (Half)* (16 bit per channel) or *Float (Full)* (32 bit per channel). The latter is advisable in order to have the same floating point precision as the original render passes.

There are several options for [codecs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/image_formats.html#output-options). They can be divided into two categories, *lossy* and *lossless*. The lossy codecs produce a smaller file size, but you're losing information through the compression. This should often be imperceptible, but may be undesirable for some compositing tasks, e.g. Cryptomatte. Unless you're constrained by limited storage space, I'd recommend using a lossless codec. In my tests it seemed that the PIZ codec is good trade-off between file size and encoding speed among the lossless codecs.

If you want to use the multi-layer OpenEXR files in other applications of your production pipeline, check if they support the codec you're intending to use before you start rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and comprehensive answer! You will go to Blender heaven!