# What are Multipass and crypto mattes?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-passes, cryptomatte

I have animated a character with texture. I want to composite / integrate it into my reallife footage. I have heard about multipass compositing is it possible to get different passes rendered from blender? And what is cryptomatte? Is it same as the multipass?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish using exclamations marks instead of periods at the end of sentences?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161207/how-to-save-render-layers-for-later-use/161210#161210